# jQuery - show() hide()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Dispongo de un botón llamado "nueva"...

```
<input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="nueva" id="nueva" value="Añadir">
```

Quiero que al seleccionarlo o hacer click, se abra un formulario/div para rellenar unos datos.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="anadir" id="anadir" method="POST">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"/></label><br/><br/>
        <label for="capacidad">Capacidad: </label>
        <?php
        echo "<select name='capacidad'>";
        for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
            if($i==1){
                echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
            }else{
                echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
            }
        }
        echo "</select>";
        ?><br/><br/>
        <label for="descripcion">Descripción: </label><input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion"/></label><br/><br/>
        <label for="precio">Precio: </label><input type="text" id="precio" name="precio"/></label><br/><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="guardar" name="guardar"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Resetear" id="resetear" name="resetear"/>
    </form>
```

**Dudas:**

1) ¿Por qué se abre pero se cierra al segundo? Sin dar opción a rellenar datos.

2) ¿Cómo se podría valorar si todos los campos están rellenados, y pulsamos "Guardar", cierre el formulario?

**Código jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#anadir').hide();
    $("#nueva_cabana").on("click", function() {
        $('#anadir').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El boton es un `submit` por lo tanto hace postback cuando lo clicas y refresca la vista. Pon uno normal.

Aqui un par de detallitos mas:

1. Tienes mal muchas etiquetas de cierre en los labels.
2. Tienes mal la identificacion del boton en jquery.
3. Te recomiendo usar [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), asi te servira para mostrar y ocultar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#anadir').hide();
  $("#nueva").on("click", function() {
    $('#anadir').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="nueva" id="nueva" value="Añadir">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="anadir" id="anadir" method="POST">
  <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
  <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" />
  <br/><br/>
  <label for="capacidad">Capacidad: </label>
  <?php
  echo "<select name='capacidad'>";
  for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
      if($i==1){
          echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
      }else{
          echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
      }
  }
  echo "</select>";
  ?>
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="descripcion">Descripción: </label>
    <input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" />
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="precio">Precio: </label>
    <input type="text" id="precio" name="precio" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="guardar" name="guardar" />
    <input type="reset" value="Resetear" id="resetear" name="resetear" />
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias por lo de las etiquetas <label> fue motivo de "copy-paste", y sí el motivo era el botón "submit" debido a que no envía resultados, simplemente hace efecto de "click". Es decir: "button".

Comment: Sí, debo esperar 4 minutos.... ;)